# lower case to uppercase conversion

Tags: linux, bash

I found solution but it doesn't working http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-programming-converting-lowercase-uppercase/

```
[root@mg0016 tmp]# y="this Is A test"
[root@mg0016 tmp]# echo "${y^^}"
-bash: ${y^^}: bad substitution
```

Comment: `y="this Is A test"; y=${echo $y|tr "a-z" "A-Z"}`;echo y: $y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any one of the following code :

```
$ tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```

or

```
$  sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: The sed form isn't very portable (AFAIK it's GNU sed specific). The portable sed version would be `sed -e 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/' input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: @user1598202 - +1: great reply!

Answer (score 0):

I found following one! and it works!

```
[spatel@mg0016 ~]$ echo "lower" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
LOWER
```

Thanks for reply all.